# Play Framework Response Size Limitation

Tags: playframework-2.0

I know that there is a default limit of 100kb on the request messages that the client sends to one of the controllers in my Play project. What about the size on the response messages? I have a huge String JSON that I want to send as a response. Is there anything that I have to specify additionally in Play framework to handle such huge Strings in the response messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers have certain limitations, but other than that, the memory is the limit. You should however [stream large responses](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaStream) in order to avoid clogging up RAM.